# Cassandra: One big table or many small tables?

Tags: database-design, cassandra

I have several tables each of the same schema. Each of the tables belong to a different API but all return the same structure. So, should I use one table for all APIs with API id as a key or should I create a separate table for each API?

Comment: You can use a single table. You don't have to prepared statements for each  api

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your data model, but the usual approach with Cassandra is to have model query-driven, that is one table per query. In your case I'd stick with one table (how many APIs? A table has a memory overhead, you really can't go past a few... hundred).

That being said, having only the API id as a key would probably kill your cluster due to wide partitions. You should carefully model the table in order to satisfy *one* query, and if you have more query you should add more tables (or materialized views).